# How to assign three different value to three the same variables

Tags: php, variables

I don't know if there is a way out of this...... How can three different values be assigned to the same variable differently and echo or print the variable? Just like the code below.

```
  $A = 'A';
  $A = 'B';
   $A = 'C';

   echo $A;
```

If I echo $A we all know it going to get the last variable, so how am I going to get all the values once.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Do none of the answers below give you a usable solution? If not you should explain why. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. You can't give a variable multiple different values simultaneously. If you want to echo each value as it's assigned, then you can do that: `$A = 'A'; echo $A; $A = 'B'; echo $A;  $A = 'C';  echo $A;`...but I can't really see why that would be useful.

Comment: All the answers below really work, thanks to them. If the question is not detailed or clarified why do other people who provided answers get the point of the question. You are just flagging and downvoting unnecessarily. Thanks for your answers

Comment: If the answers helped you then why haven't you accepted any of them? None of them are marked accepted. Therefore it looks like you didn't like them. The question is still ambiguous btw - if you look, the answers are between them suggesting multiple possible solutions because they're not entirely clear what it is you want. They produce some different outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array of values like this:

```
$A = [];
$A[] = 'A';
$A[] = 'B';
$A[] = 'C';

echo $A[0];
...
echo $A[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use array not variable, a variable can hold single value at a time.
there is different way to achieve this

```
$A = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
print_r($A);
```

OR

```
$A[] = 'A';
$A[] = 'B';
$A[] = 'C';
print_r($A);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
)
```

OR

```
$A = 'A';
$A .= 'B';
$A .= 'C';
echo $A;
```

OUTPUT

```
ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

simple and ugly way

```
<?php
 $A = 'A';
 $A .= 'B';
 $A .= 'C';

 echo $A;
```

OUTPUT

```
ABC
```